# Adding event listeners to multiple elements

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I've been struggling with this for a good couple of hours now.

I want to add an event listener to all `<select>`s on a page and I've got this piece of code so far:

```
onload = function(e) {
    sels = document.getElementsByTagName('select');
    for(i=0; i<sels.length; i++) {
        sels[i].addEventListener('change', alert('test!'), false);
    }
}
```

This only triggers the alert when the page is loaded and not when I change the value in any of my `<select>`s.

Can I get a nudge in the right direction, please? :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to have there anonymous function for that as you invoke `alert()` function immediately in your example:

```
 ... .addEventListener('change', function() { alert('test!')}, false ...
```

For now according to your code `addEventListener` tries to add result of `undefined` (return of `alert()` function).

Or you can just pass function handler for that:

```
function alertMe() {
    alert( 'test!' );
}
...

... .addEventListener('change', alertMe, false ...
```

Note: that by making `somefunction(arg[, arg...])` call you reference not to function, but to what function returns.

Comment: Oh. I was positive I'd tried that, but apparently not. Thank you!

Edit: I see. Now that you mention it it makes sense to me.

Comment: @Perplexor Are you sure? I'm not seeing another error in your code.

Comment: Of course I tried it in some other circumstances, which is why it didn't work at that time. But now it works with your solution!

Answer (score 6):

Aside from wrapping the `alert` in a function, like mentioned before, don't use `getElementsByTagName` for every iteration of the loop:

```
onload = function(e) {
    sels = document.getElementsByTagName('select');
    for(i=0; i<sels.length; i++) {
        sels[i].addEventListener('change', function(){alert('test!')}, false);
    }
}
```

You have the list of `select` elements saved to a variable, it's not necessary, not to mention inefficient to `get` all these elements, each loop iteration.

Comment: Good point! I actually just used "trial and error" to get the result I wanted. That's why I did like that. Thank you!

Comment: No problem, "Trial and Error" is, in my opinion, the only way to really learn to program, so good job :P

Comment: Helpful answer, Do you know any faster way? I mean getElementByTagName may be a little slow

Comment: @M98 You can give a class to all the elements you want to add listener to the call `getElementsByClassName()`. Which should be a little faster.

Answer (score 1):

I created the following simple function, which iterates over all of the elements that match the `selector`, and add an event listener for the `event` with the passed `handler`.

This is similar functionality for jQuery's `$(selector).on(event, handler)`

```
function addEventListeners(selector, event, handler, useCapture){

    useCapture = useCapture || false;

    Array.prototype.forEach.call(
        document.querySelectorAll(selector)
       ,function(el, ix) { 
          el.addEventListener(event, handler, useCapture);
        }
    );
}
```

So for the OP the way to use this function would be like so:

```
addEventListeners("select", "change", function(evt){ console.log(evt); });
```

See also my answer for [Event listener for current and future elements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45705202/968244)

Answer (score 0):

You are executing the alert() function immediately, you need to pass the addEventListener function a function instead, so:

```
onload = function(e) {
    sels = document.getElementsByTagName('select');
    for(i=0; i<sels.length; i++) {
        document.getElementsByTagName('select')[i].addEventListener('change', function () { alert('test!'); }, false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Event Bubbling is the important concept in javascript, so if you can add event on DOM directly, you can save some lines of code :

```
document.addEventListener('change', function(e){
  if(e.target.tagName=="SELECT"){
   alert('SELECT CHANGED');
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I always recommend delegation - if the inputs are in the same container, then you can do this

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() { // on page load
  document  // or a closer static container
    .addEventListener("input", function(e) { // input or change
    const tgt = e.target;
    if (tgt.tagName === "SELECT") {
      const id = tgt.id;
      console.log("You changed", id)
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<div id="inputContainer">
  <h1>Change the select</h1>
  <select id="sel1">
    <option value="">Please select</option>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
  </select>
  <select id="sel2">
    <option value="">Please select</option>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
  </select>
</div>
```