# Event listener for current and future elements Without jQuery

Tags: javascript, dom-events, web-standards

If I remember correctly, I once saw a method to bind event listeners to every single element that matches a certain criteria, a query selector maybe. Looking for it again I cannot find anything other than people highly dependent on jQuery but I prefer a real simple way to achieve this.

Anyone knows what is this method called?

Comment: `elem.addEventListener('event',function);`?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_eventlistener.asp

Comment: Here's a far better solution: [addEventListener to future DOM elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71809473/383904)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The method you are looking for is called *event capturing*.  You can do it like this:

```
document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
    // Do some check on target
    if ( evt.target.classList.contains('some-class') ) {
        // DO CODE
    }
}, true); // Use Capturing
```

Comment: I remember what I saw was a bit more sophisticate but I see your solution will work well enough so I am picking it while nothing better comes up. Thanks.

Comment: So, the "capturing" part will ensure that it will work if I click on a child element?

Answer (score 8):

I wrote a more general-purpose function which takes a selector, event-type, and a handler function, akin to jQuery's `on` function:

```
/** adds a live event handler akin to jQuery's on() */
function addLiveEventListeners(selector, event, handler){
    document.querySelector("body").addEventListener(
         event
        ,function(evt){
            var target = evt.target;
            while (target != null){
                var isMatch = target.matches(selector);
                if (isMatch){
                    handler(evt);
                    return;
                }
                target = target.parentElement;
            }
        }
        ,true
    );
}
```

For example, the following will be called for any click on a div, even if it was added to the DOM at a later time:

```
addLiveEventListeners("div", "click", function(evt){ console.log(evt); });
```

This works on all modern browsers and Microsoft Edge.  To make it work in IE9 -- IE11 the test `target.matches(selector)` should be modified like so:

```
var isMatch = target.matches ? target.matches(selector) : target.msMatchesSelector(selector);
```

and then the test `if (isMatch)` will work for those browsers as well.

See also my answer for [Adding event listeners to multiple elements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45704806/968244) which adds the event listeners to the elements themselves rather than to `body`.

Comment: This answer may be getting a bit old, but you can furthermore mimic jQuery's "on" method by replacing the call to handler by this :
`handler.call(target, evt);`
This way you get the same behavior where `this` refers to the element firing the event according to your selector, while you still get the original target in the event's properties.