# Transforming a child element on hover with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to have an icon that switches class when the parent div is hovered.
So far, here is my code:

```
var actionIcon = document.querySelector(".task > svg")
var taskContainer = document.querySelector(".task")

function iconScale() {
  actionIcon.classList.toggle('big');
}

taskContainer.onmouseenter = iconScale
taskContainer.onmouseleave = iconScale
```

And the HTML:

```
<div class="task">
  <h3>Title</h3>
  <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24">
    <path d="..." />
  </svg>
</div>
```

My issue is that the effect I am trying to achieve is only happening on the very first parent element and none of the other ones.
I'm pretty sure I am not specifying something but I don't know what. Anyone could give me a hint?

Comment: can you post the accompanying HTML. Have you used console to check you have an object (i.e. is you querySelector working. ). Also is the code being correctly executed when DOM has loaded?

Comment: Oh sorry. Missed that. There are multiple of these?

Comment: Yep that's where I'm stuck.

Comment: Fixed answer. Should work for you now. (please up vote.)

Comment: no need to use JS  and `.big {`  --> `.task:hover svg { background-color: blue; }` is enough

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to addeventlistener to multiple elements in a single line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40956717/how-to-addeventlistener-to-multiple-elements-in-a-single-line)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed code to map to ALL divs that are tasks. Cannot use querySelector as it only returns first instance.

```js
const actionIcon = (parent) => {
  return parent.querySelector('svg');
};

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

  // Add events to ALL divs that conform
  let tasks = document.getElementsByClassName('task');
  
  for(let t of tasks) {
    t.onmouseenter = iconScale;
    t.onmouseleave = iconScale;
  }

  function iconScale(event) {
    let icon = actionIcon(event.target);
    icon.classList.toggle('big');
  }
});
```

```css
svg {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: red;
} 

.big {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="task">
  <h3>Title</h3>
  <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24">
    
  </svg>
</div>
<div class="task">
  <h3>Title</h3>
  <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24">
    
  </svg>
</div>
<div class="task">
  <h3>Title</h3>
  <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24">
    
  </svg>
</div>
<div class="task">
  <h3>Title</h3>
  <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24">
    
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: My CSS is as simple as in your example (.big{transform: scale(1.2);}). I tried to modify my code as you suggested but nothing changes... It just works for the first element and not the other ones. Am I not missing something like specifying the div when it's hovered??

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks a lot for your help :)

Comment: Most welcome. Ensure you include the `DOMContentLoaded` call as this ensures your DOM content is loaded and ready to bind events.

Comment: is yours DIV.task have the same parent ?

Comment: Note that you can also use `querySelectorAll` to get all matches instead of just the first one.

Comment: Also, there is a difference between [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) and [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of). You should be using `for...of` here, because `for...in` also returns some additional properties that you should not be adding `.onmouseenter/.onmouseleave` to.

Comment: @Herohtar thanks for tip have edited code to reflect you for .. of comment. My bad

Answer (score 2):

You asked for JavaScript, but as an alternative and simpler example, you don't even need to use JavaScript; what you want can be done entirely in CSS:

```css
svg {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}

.task:hover svg {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="task">
  <h3>Title</h3>
  <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24">
    
  </svg>
</div>
<div class="task">
  <h3>Title</h3>
  <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24">
    
  </svg>
</div>
<div class="task">
  <h3>Title</h3>
  <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24">
    
  </svg>
</div>
<div class="task">
  <h3>Title</h3>
  <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24">
    
  </svg>
</div>
```