# How can I attach one or more variables to one event listener?

Tags: javascript

I have an event listener inside of an if statement to make a menu slide in.

```
const burger = document.querySelector(".c-brgr");

if (!menuOpen) {
    burger.addEventListener('click', function () {
      if (!menuOpen) {
        nav.classList.add("menu-is-open");
        menuOpen = true;
      } else {
        nav.classList.remove("menu-is-open");
        menuOpen = false;
      }
   });
}
```

I also have a div within the HTML that I'd like when clicked, to also close the menu. I could just make another.

```
const closeArea = document.querySelector(".js-close-area");

if (!menuOpen) {
    closeArea.addEventListener('click', function () {
      if (!menuOpen) {
       // as above
      } else {
       // "
      }
   });
}
```

This time, instead of burger, I use the other element. `closeArea`. This will repeat code, however, unnecessarily.

Is there a way I can use just one if statement for both `addEventListeners`?

Comment: Give them a common class, select all elements with that class, loop through them, and apply your `addEventListener` to the current element in the iteration.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to addeventlistener to multiple elements in a single line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40956717/how-to-addeventlistener-to-multiple-elements-in-a-single-line)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can add both to an array, and loop through them as follows

```
    const burger = document.querySelector(".c-brgr");
    const closeArea = document.querySelector(".js-close-area");

    if (!menuOpen) {
        [burger, closeArea].forEach(element => {
          element.addEventListener('click', function () {
             if (!menuOpen) {
               // as above
              } else {
                // "
              }
           });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You are currently using an anonymous function as your event listener. To avoid repeating the code, use a named function instead:

```
function toggleMenu() {
   // if statement goes here
}
```

Now you can add this as the event listener on any item you want:

```
burger.addEventListener('click', toggleMenu);
closeArea.addEventListener('click', toggleMenu);
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is a concept to use function that return functions. This may sound complicated at first, but you can have the advantage later by wrapping in some extra variables that you like to access later.

This way, you are able to create multiple functions, each with their own separate and independent state or values. All invoked from the same wrapper function.

This method will scale easily if you add more buttons as you can store separate state for each button while using the same code.

```js
// create a function that returns a function
function binder(param1, param2) {
  return function () {
      // triggered on event call, so this will be executed later
      console.log(param1, param2);
  }
}

// here are variables you want to access later
var var1 = 'foo';
var var2 = 'bar';

// pass the variables to the binder function
// this will create a function with access to the variables you need
closeArea.addEventListener('click', binder(var1, var2));
```

So you can do this

```
const burger = document.querySelector(".c-brgr");

// Create a function to create a handler function that has access to it's own variables later on
function createMenuClickHandler(nav) {
    // Given the started value is always the same, you can choose to not pass parameters
    // every time you call this function, you get a function with it's own independent menuOpen value
    const menuOpen = false; 

    return function() {
        // You usual business
        if (!menuOpen) {
            nav.classList.add("menu-is-open");
            menuOpen = true;
        } else {
            nav.classList.remove("menu-is-open");
            menuOpen = false;
        }
    }
}

// You may store the result of createMenuClickHandler if you want to share the same state on other places in your code as well
// If you want a separate state, call createMenuClickHandler again
closeArea.addEventListener('click', createMenuClickHandler(burger));
```