# Pure Javascript: What is the best way to click a button in the group of buttons in a calculator?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this code that I built in HTML/CSS that's based on Mac/Apple calculator. The way it's displayed is that buttons are grouped in 5 rows using flexbox.

Here's my code from this [codepen](https://codepen.io/kikibres/pen/RwrBXKv?editors=1111):

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="calheader">
      <h2>Simple Calculator</h2>
    </div>
  <div class="calculatorbox">
    <div class="calwindow">
      <!-- ENTRY BOX -->
     <div class="entry">
        <p id="answer"></p>
      </div>
      <div class="entryhistory">
        <p id="history"></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- BUTTONS \\-->
    <div class="calbuttons">
      <div class="row">
        <button id="clear" class="key topcolor" value="clear">C</button>
        <button class="key topcolor" value="plusminus"><sup>+</sup>/<sub>−</sub></button>
        <button class="key topcolor" value="%">%</button>
        <button id="divide" class="key orange" value="/">÷</button>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <button id="seven" class="key" value="7">7</button>
        <button id="eight" class="key" value="8">8</button>
        <button id="nine" class="key" value="9">9</button>
        <button id="multiply" class="key orange" value="*">×</button>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <button id="four" class="key" value="4">4</button>
        <button id="five" class="key" value="5">5</button>
        <button id="six" class="key" value="6">6</button>
        <button id="subtract" class="key orange" value="-">−</button>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <button id="one" class="key" value="1">1</button>
        <button id="two" class="key" value="2">2</button>
        <button id="three" class="key" value="3">3</button>
        <button id="add" class="key orange" value="+">+</button>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <button id="zero" class="key btnspan" value="0">0</button>
        <button id="decimal" class="key" value=".">.</button>
        <button id="equals" class="key orange" value="=">=</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now, I'm trying to figure out how to select the button so that I can use `addEventListener` to each button.

Other pure javascript tutorial I have checked out only has this display:

```
<div class="calculator-keys">
    
    <button type="button" class="operator" value="+">+</button>
    <button type="button" class="operator" value="-">-</button>
    <button type="button" class="operator" value="*">&times;</button>
    <button type="button" class="operator" value="/">&divide;</button>

    <button type="button" value="7">7</button>
    <button type="button" value="8">8</button>
    <button type="button" value="9">9</button>


    <button type="button" value="4">4</button>
    <button type="button" value="5">5</button>
    <button type="button" value="6">6</button>


    <button type="button" value="1">1</button>
    <button type="button" value="2">2</button>
    <button type="button" value="3">3</button>


    <button type="button" value="0">0</button>
    <button type="button" class="decimal" value=".">.</button>
    <button type="button" class="all-clear" value="all-clear">AC</button>

    <button type="button" class="equal-sign operator" value="=">=</button>

  </div>
```

so that he will be able to use this code:

```
const keys = document.querySelector('.calculator-keys');

keys.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  const { target } = event;
  console.log('digit', target.value);
});
```

What I understand is that this tutorial I've checked out use `querySelector` to select all the children within the class `calculator-keys`.

In my case, I was able to make it work for only the first row. However, if I use `querySelectorAll`, do I need to use `.map()`, `.forEach()`, or something else in order to use `addEventListener` on each button?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to addEventListener to multiple elements in a single line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40956717/how-to-addeventlistener-to-multiple-elements-in-a-single-line)

Comment: Agree to @kmoser but you cannot use map function because querySelectorAll() returns a HTML collection instead of javascript array. So that you have to use forEach or write for loop to iterate elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`querySelector` return only one element so you need to use `querySelectorAll`
you need to select all elements with class `key` and then add event listener for each key

```js
 const keys = document.querySelectorAll('.key');

keys.forEach(item => {
 item.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    const { target } = event;
    console.log('digit', target.value);
    });
});
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="calheader">
      <h2>Simple Calculator</h2>
    </div>
  <div class="calculatorbox">
    <div class="calwindow">
      <!-- ENTRY BOX -->
     <div class="entry">
        <p id="answer"></p>
      </div>
      <div class="entryhistory">
        <p id="history"></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- BUTTONS \\-->
    <div class="calbuttons">
      <div class="row">
        <button id="clear" class="key topcolor" value="clear">C</button>
        <button class="key topcolor" value="plusminus"><sup>+</sup>/<sub>−</sub></button>
        <button class="key topcolor" value="%">%</button>
        <button id="divide" class="key orange" value="/">÷</button>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <button id="seven" class="key" value="7">7</button>
        <button id="eight" class="key" value="8">8</button>
        <button id="nine" class="key" value="9">9</button>
        <button id="multiply" class="key orange" value="*">×</button>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <button id="four" class="key" value="4">4</button>
        <button id="five" class="key" value="5">5</button>
        <button id="six" class="key" value="6">6</button>
        <button id="subtract" class="key orange" value="-">−</button>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <button id="one" class="key" value="1">1</button>
        <button id="two" class="key" value="2">2</button>
        <button id="three" class="key" value="3">3</button>
        <button id="add" class="key orange" value="+">+</button>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <button id="zero" class="key btnspan" value="0">0</button>
        <button id="decimal" class="key" value=".">.</button>
        <button id="equals" class="key orange" value="=">=</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Dom event deligation refers to handling bubbling events from many elements. It can keep the code simpler, especially when adding or removing elements, and saves some memory.

**Some code examples of event delegation:**

1. [JavaScript Event Delegation](http://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate)
2. [DOM Events](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html)

If you are using `Javascript` and you have a list of buttons with class '`key`', you can use this code to add an [EventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventListener) to each button.

```
let buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('key');
    for(let i = 0; i<buttons.length; i++){
       buttons[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
          /*add your code here*/
       });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

querySelectoAll returns a NodeList, you can create an array from buttons, iterate and assign an eventListener

```js
let buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');
let arrButtons = Array.from(buttons);

console.log(arrButtons)

for(button of arrButtons){
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.log('event');
  })
}
```

```html
<button class="btn">Go!</button>
<button class="btn">Go!</button>
<button class="btn">Go!</button>
<button class="btn">Go!</button>
```

Comment: i cant add an Edit-suggest for some reason but shouldn't we use a different id for each button?

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation). This way you don't have to attach event listener on each button, but only on their parent container.

```js
const calculator = document.querySelector(".calculator-keys");

// only attach click event on the container
calculator.addEventListener("click", (event) => {

  // ignore clicks from non-button element
  if (event.target.nodeName !== "BUTTON") return;

  console.log(event.target.value);
});
```

```html
<div class="calculator-keys">
  <button type="button" class="operator" value="+">+</button>
  <button type="button" class="operator" value="-">-</button>
  <button type="button" class="operator" value="*">&times;</button>
  <button type="button" class="operator" value="/">&divide;</button>

  <button type="button" value="7">7</button>
  <button type="button" value="8">8</button>
  <button type="button" value="9">9</button>

  <button type="button" value="4">4</button>
  <button type="button" value="5">5</button>
  <button type="button" value="6">6</button>

  <button type="button" value="1">1</button>
  <button type="button" value="2">2</button>
  <button type="button" value="3">3</button>

  <button type="button" value="0">0</button>
  <button type="button" class="decimal" value=".">.</button>
  <button type="button" class="all-clear" value="all-clear">AC</button>

  <button type="button" class="equal-sign operator" value="=">=</button>
</div>
```