# Javascript function to every textfield that calls the function

Tags: javascript, html

I have written a simple javascript function that takes the input of a date textfield and convert it to dd-mm-yyyy format.

```js
function dateConvert(dateValue) {
 if(dateValue == null) {
   var grDate = null;
 }
 else {
  var n = dateValue.search("/"); 
    if( n >= 0) {
    var res = dateValue.split("/");
    var day = res[0];
     if( day.length == 1 ) {
      day = "0"+day;     
     }
    var month = res[1];
     if( month.length == 1 ) {
      month = "0"+month;     
     }
    var year = res[2];
    var grDate = day+"-"+month+"-"+year;
    /*alert(grDate);*/
    }
   else {
    var grDate = dateValue; 
   }
 }

document.getElementById("mydate").value = grDate;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="mydate" id="mydate" onblur="dateConvert(this.value)" />
```

Is there a way to make function "global" and use it to every textfield that calls the function without having to write it e.g. 3 times if I want to use it in 3 different date textfields?

Comment: Add an event listener to `input` with a certain data attribute or class ...

Comment: [How to addEventListener to multiple elements in a single line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40956717/how-to-addeventlistener-to-multiple-elements-in-a-single-line) and [How to add an event listener to multiple elements in JavaScript](https://flaviocopes.com/how-to-add-event-listener-multiple-elements-javascript/)

Comment: That is 100% what cusomized built-in elements are perfect for, check my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the replay to Dominik. Make my mind spin
I didn't use event listener but *querySelectorAll*
Here is the correct version. It works fine

```
function myFunction() {
var x = document.querySelectorAll(".mydate");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {    

var dateValue = x[i].value; 
 if(dateValue == null) {
     var grDate = null;
 }
 else {
    var n = dateValue.search("/"); 
      if( n >= 0) {
        var res = dateValue.split("/");
        var day = res[0];
         if( day.length == 1 ) {
            day = "0"+day;   
         }
        var month = res[1];
         if( month.length == 1 ) {
            month = "0"+month;   
         }
        var year = res[2];
        var grDate = day+"-"+month+"-"+year;
        /*alert(grDate);*/
      }
     else {
        var grDate = dateValue; 
     }
 }
x[i].value = grDate;        
}
}
```

for inputs

```
<p><input type="text" name="field1" class="mydate" onblur="myFunction()" /></p>
<p><input type="text" name="field2" class="mydate" onblur="myFunction()" /></p>
<p><input type="text" name="field3" class="mydate" onblur="myFunction()" /></p>
```

Comment: Never use inline event listeners, they are bad for a whole bunch of reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Excellent question - because this is the perfect example where a custom element solves the problem.

It's really easy:

```js
customElements.define('my-date', class extends HTMLInputElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.dateConvert = this.dateConvert.bind(this);
    this.addEventListener('blur', this.dateConvert);
  }

  dateConvert() {
    if (this.value) {
      let n, res, day, month, year;
      n = this.value.search("/");
      if (n >= 0) {
        res = this.value.split("/");
        day = res[0];
        if (day.length == 1) {
          day = "0" + day;
        }
        month = res[1];
        if (month.length == 1) {
          month = "0" + month;
        }
        year = res[2];
        this.value = `${day}-${month}-${year}`;
      } 
    }
  }
}, { extends: 'input' });
```

```html
<input is="my-date" />
```

Now you can even add new date inputs dynamically and they come with your behaviour automatically. **No fuddling around in the DOM, just an element that does exactly what you need any time it's in the HTML anywhere.**

Please note that unfortunately Safari does not support customizing built-in elements, so you either will have to resort to a polyfill (check https://github.com/webcomponents/polyfills/tree/master/packages/custom-elements or https://github.com/ungap/custom-elements#readme) for that, or use an autonomous custom elements like this:

```js
customElements.define('my-date', class extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.input = document.createElement('input');
    this.appendChild(this.input);
    this.dateConvert = this.dateConvert.bind(this);
    this.input.addEventListener('blur', this.dateConvert);
  }

  dateConvert() {
    if (this.value) {
      let n, res, day, month, year;
      n = this.value.search("/");
      if (n >= 0) {
        res = this.value.split("/");
        day = res[0];
        if (day.length == 1) {
          day = "0" + day;
        }
        month = res[1];
        if (month.length == 1) {
          month = "0" + month;
        }
        year = res[2];
        this.value = `${day}-${month}-${year}`;
      } 
    }
  }
  
  get value() {
    return this.input.value;
  }
  
  set value(val) {
    this.input.value = val;
  }
});
```

```html
<my-date></my-date>
```

Just as a sidenote, you might want to consider using the built-in API for dateTime conversion/formatting:

> https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat

Comment: Thanks a lot for the replay connexo. That was a great answer. Above everything you made me search and learn.