# Copy the header to input

Tags: javascript

There are several identical blocks with a header and a button under it tell me how to copy the header to input when the button is pressed. How do I handle multiple buttons and headers?

if there is only one header then this code works

```js
const modalTitle = document.querySelector('.popup_wrap>h3');
const modalBtn = document.querySelector('.popup-btn');
const resInp = document.querySelector('.research-title');

modalBtn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  resInp.value = modalTitle.innerHTML;
});
```

```html
<div class="popup_wrap">
  <h3>Title</h3>
  <a class="popup-btn" data-modal="5">Click</a>
</div>
<div class="popup_wrap">
  <h3>Title2</h3>
  <a class="popup-btn" data-modal="5">Click</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Please finish your question with a "?" ex. *How do I handle multiple buttons and headers?*

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to addEventListener to multiple elements in a single line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40956717/how-to-addeventlistener-to-multiple-elements-in-a-single-line)

Comment: Instead of selecting with a global `.popup_wrap > h3`, use the `this` inside the event listener to track your way to the title (e.g. `this.parentElement.querySelector('h3')`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this: `previousElementSibling` gets the precedent node at the same level inside the parent.

If you have nodes in between you can repeat the process until you find a `h3`. (Or use `this.parentElement.querySelector('h3')` as suggested in a comment)

This is a fool proof version for as many dynamically added elements without the need of ids or named function, as long as the js code runs after the elements are added.

```js
const modalBtns = document.querySelectorAll('.popup-btn');
const resInp = document.querySelector('.research-title');

for(let i = 0; i < modalBtns.length; i++){
  modalBtns[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    resInp.value = this.previousElementSibling.innerHTML;
  });
}
```

```html
<input class="research-title"/>

<div class="popup_wrap">
  <h3>Title</h3>
  <a class="popup-btn" data-modal="5">Click</a>
</div>
<div class="popup_wrap">
  <h3>Title2</h3>
  <a class="popup-btn" data-modal="5">Click</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to create a function and call it on button click like the code below

```js
function copy(id){
  const header = document.getElementById(id)
  console.log(header.innerHTML)
  // do this instead console.log
  // const resInp = document.querySelector('.research-title');
  //resInp.value = header.innerHTML
}
```

```html
<div class="popup_wrap">
        <h3 id="header-1">Title</h3>
        <a class="popup-btn" onclick="copy('header-1')" data-modal="5">Click</a>
    </div>
    <div class="popup_wrap">
        <h3 id="header-2">Title2</h3>
        <a class="popup-btn" onclick="copy('header-2')" data-modal="5">Click</a>
    </div>
```

Comment: popup_wrap - this block is created dynamically, there is no possibility to register for each of your id

Comment: you can assign an id for each one by adding the index of each item to the id like so "header-{index}", or you can change the function to pass the title directly instead of the header id. If you want i can edit the code for you

Comment: I will be very grateful to you)

Comment: it's my pleasure, but first can i know how you generate the items, i mean are you using react or vue or somthing else? so i can help you more with that.

Answer (score 0):

here is the modified code hope it will help you  :

```
function copy(header_id) {
    const header = document.getElementById(id);
    const resInp = document.querySelector('.research-title');
    resInp.value = header.innerHTML;
}

 <div class="popup_wrap">
 <h3 id="header-1">Title</h3>
 <a class="popup-btn" onclick="copy('header-1')" data-modal="5">Click</a>
 </div>
 <div class="popup_wrap">
 <h3 id="header-2">Title2</h3>
  <a class="popup-btn" onclick="copy('header-2')" data-modal="5">Click</a>
 </div>
```

Explanation :

The copy function takes an header_id parameter, which represents the ID of the header element to be copied.
Inside the function, the header element is selected using document.getElementById(id).
The resInp variable is selected using document.querySelector('.research-title') outside the copy function, assuming the input field with the class research-title exists on the page.When the button is clicked, the copy function is called with the corresponding header ID as an argument. The function retrieves the header element and assigns its innerHTML value to the resInp input field's value property, effectively copying the header text to the input field.