# Display a div using a radio buttons

Tags: javascript, css, arrays, dom-events

To reduce the number of lines of code I simplified my code to display three divs instead. What I want is to have a particular div displayed while hiding the other two divs depending on which radio button is checked.

I'm actually following these two links

[Adding event listeners to multiple elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13915702/adding-event-listeners-to-multiple-elements)

[How can I check whether a radio button is selected with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1423777/how-can-i-check-whether-a-radio-button-is-selected-with-javascript)

in the second link it was suggested to use

```
radios[i].type === 'radio' && radios[i].checked
```

for the test.

however I modified it to just

```
DisplayOption[i].checked
```

since its all I think i need. The error I'm receiving is

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'checked' of undefined

```js
const column = document.querySelector('.column');
const table = document.querySelector('.table');
const details = document.querySelector('.details');

onload = function() {
  const DisplayOption = document.getElementsByClassName("DisplayOption");
  for (i = 0; i < DisplayOption.length; i++) {
    DisplayOption[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
      if (DisplayOption[i].checked) {
        if (displyOption[i].value === "column") {
          column.style.display = "grid";
          table.style.display = "none";
          table.details.style.display = "none";
        } else if (displyOption[i].value === "table") {
          column.style.display = "none";
          table.style.display = "block";
          table.details.style.display = "none";
        } else {
          column.style.display = "none";
          table.style.display = "none";
          table.details.style.display = "block";
        }
      }
    }, false);
  }
}
```

```css
.column {
  display: grid;
}

.table {
  display: none;
}

.table.details {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="DisplayOption" value="column" class="DisplayOption" checked>
<input type="radio" name="DisplayOption" value="table" class="DisplayOption">
<input type="radio" name="DisplayOption" value="details" class="DisplayOption">


<div class="column"> The first div is being displayed </div>
<div class="table"> The second div is being displayed</div>
<div class="table details"> The third div is being displayed </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the *eventListener*, to refer to the element being clicked use `this` instead of `DisplayOption[i]`. Another bug was using `table.details` - it should be only `details`. See corrected demo below:

```js
const column = document.querySelector('.column');
const table = document.querySelector('.table');
const details = document.querySelector('.details');

onload = function() {
  const DisplayOption = document.getElementsByClassName("DisplayOption");
  for (i = 0; i < DisplayOption.length; i++) {
    DisplayOption[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
      if (this.checked) {
        if (this.value === "column") {
          column.style.display = "grid";
          table.style.display = "none";
          details.style.display = "none";
        } else if (this.value === "table") {
          column.style.display = "none";
          table.style.display = "block";
          details.style.display = "none";
        } else {
          column.style.display = "none";
          table.style.display = "none";
          details.style.display = "block";
        }
      }
    }, false);
  }
}
```

```css
.column {
  display: grid;
}

.table {
  display: none;
}

.table.details {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="DisplayOption" value="column" class="DisplayOption" checked>
<input type="radio" name="DisplayOption" value="table" class="DisplayOption">
<input type="radio" name="DisplayOption" value="details" class="DisplayOption">


<div class="column"> The first div is being displayed </div>
<div class="table"> The second div is being displayed</div>
<div class="table details"> The third div is being displayed </div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm not too familiar with the this keyword.To be honest I try to avoid as much as possible :). I should really change that.

Answer (score 2):

You could achieve the same using CSS ! No need of javascript !

You can make use of the `sibling` (~) selector in CSS and display the corresponding `div`

```css
div {
  display: none;
}

input[value="column"]:checked~.column,
input[value="table"]:checked~.table,
input[value="details"]:checked~.details {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="DisplayOption" value="column" class="DisplayOption" checked>
<input type="radio" name="DisplayOption" value="table" class="DisplayOption">
<input type="radio" name="DisplayOption" value="details" class="DisplayOption">


<div class="column"> The first div is being displayed </div>
<div class="table"> The second div is being displayed</div>
<div class="details"> The third div is being displayed </div>
```

[JSFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/rx4cak56/2/)

Comment: This is really nice :) and simple. but the first div needs to be display grid not block.

Comment: You could declare the `input[value="column"]:checked~.column { display: grid }` separately :)

Comment: Even though I selected the first answer because It addresses the error in the question,  I'm using your simple  solution. Thanks mate!

Comment: Cheers ! Good luck !