# How do I rotate the whole web page to a certain degree including all the elements on the page?

Tags: html, css

I want to rotate the whole web page to a certain degree(45 degree) including all the elements on the page.

The answers that I found is not working on all the elements of the web page.

Comment: Please don't edit your question to something that has no relevance  to the original question. Please ask a new question instead. In regards to the new question, this should help : https://stackoverflow.com/a/13915850/4665

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For rotating

```
body { transform: rotate(20deg); }
```

Comment: I have already said that in my query that it's not working for the elements that are inside the body. Just the outside container is getting affected by it.

Comment: I tested it @Kundan , it works well. Add CSS transform code to the body tag,  If you still facing the problem then send us a code. We will solve it.